# flutter: android manifest doesn't read kotlin file (Application.kt)

Tags: flutter, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I'm trying to imply firebase cloud messaging to my app and I have tried to add both MainActvity.kt and Application.kt to my project and i didnt have kotlin installed on my project so i downloaded kotlin plugin then restarted my IDE then added the .kt files, however when i try to add the application.kt to my android manifest the app won't build and says "app" has stopped, but without it it works fine, what am i doing wrong?

heres my application.kt code

```
package com.example.tamataapp

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
    }
}
```

and my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.tamataapp

import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
        // getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    }
}
```

and here is my android manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tamataapp">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" -->
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="tamataapp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="default_notification_channel_id”>Channel ID"/>
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <service
            android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the Flutter project is yet to be configured to support Kotlin for Android. You can follow this [guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) to upgrade your Flutter project.

Another alternative would be upgrading the Flutter SDK that you're using by running `flutter upgrade` along with the Flutter plugin that you're using in the IDE. Creating a new Flutter project after this, the Android build should be Kotlin by default.